# What is the meaning of "on an exceptional basis"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

I read an english version document, and there's some words i dont quite understand (since english is not my main language), especially the "on an exceptional basis" part, can you help me guys? Thanks before.

the full paragraph is:

A substance tracked for information purposes only, upon decision by the GASG Steering Committee. After discussion at the GASG Steering Committee and on an exceptional basis, an automobile manufacturer may include an individual substance or family of substances on the list under this (FI) reason code.

Comment: Often foreign companies (from non-English speaking countries) invent their own internal language to mean something specific. And the translations are often so bad as to be incomprehensible to a native English speaker. I have no idea what this paragraph means. If you could explain it in better English, your question could be answered.(I`m a native English speaking lawyer).

Comment: Hi john, i am sorry for the late respond and bad details of my question, basically i want to know the definition of the words "on an exceptional basis", and what would that words meant especially the paragraph above.

Anyway could you give me better examples of sentences using "on an exceptional basis" and their meaning? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this purpose, a close enough definition is **in special circumstances.**

It is saying that a manufacturer can only use a listed substance if given an exception from the rule. And exceptions would only be given in special circumstances. The opposite is “on a routine basis” which means something that is done often and without special circumstances. An exception from a rule can be given on a routine basis, but in your paragraph they are saying that it would be allowed by the committee only on an exceptional basis.

Comment: Thanks damila for the explanation, have a nice day.